# Is there a commonly used notation for flipped composition?

Tags: notation

We have $ (f \circ g) = x \mapsto f(g(x)) $ however since I read left to write it always seems backwards to me.  Is there a symbol like $ ( g \ggg f) = x \mapsto f(g(x)) $.

It is especially grating in situations like.

$$ 
\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} X @>{f \circ g}>> Y \\ 
@VVgV @AAfA \\
g(X) @>{id}>> g(X)\end{CD}
$$

Comment: I've seen people denote $g(f(x))$ by $(f\circ g)(x)$ in the context of group theory.

Comment: That's unpleasantly ambitious :(

Comment: I think the idea is that $f$ and $g$ appear in the same order in both notations. That's what we get for having left-hand function notation. Were I to go back in time to the ancient Greeks and reboot mathematics, I would establish the notation $(x)f$ (or maybe use something different from parentheses). Along with establishing $6.28$ as the circle constant (I would probably still call it $\pi$, for "perimeter", though), and the electron as positively charged.

Comment: @QthePlatypus Actually that's not what I've seen. Arthur's comment reminded me of it. What I've seen is $(x)(f\circ g)$ denoting $g(f(x))$.

Comment: If you write your functions on the right, $x \mapsto xf$, then $fg$ means first do $f$ then $g$. Too bad the convention of writing functions to the left of their arguments got started a long time ago.

Answer (score 5):

Computer scientists may write `g ; f` for `f ∘ g`

See:[Function composition - Alternative notations](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Function_composition#/Alternative_notations)

Answer (score 1):

I *personally* use the notation $f$»$g$, which is inspired by the F# operator >>. Perhaps you like that too, although it isn't established by any means.

---

In LaTeX it should be `\text{\guillemotright}` with:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

and

```
 \usepackage{amsmath}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some math books (especially abstract algebra) may write composition in the reverse order: $\sigma\tau$ means: **first $\sigma$ then $\tau$**.  For notation they write
$$
  x^{\sigma \tau} = \big(x^\sigma\big)^\tau
$$
For example, this may be seen with field automorphisms.